# I cant connect to my data base or my host from sql server 2014

Tags: sql-server

This is the error message.

[image]

I tried to restart the SQL Server service but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your Sql Server Configuration Manager, open the Sql Server Configuration Manager by running Windows + r > compmgmt.msc and then open Services and Application in it you will find SQL Server Configuration Manager.
[SQL Server Configuration Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgGA0.png)

Double click on the SQL Server Services and then you will find some services there.

[SQL Server Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mwfA.png)

What I underlined is the instance name of my SQL Server, so to login, you need to specify your [HostName]\[InstanceName].

Example : My host name is LAPTOP-OOHVP7Q7
So to connect, I need to specify my hostname and instance name
So i need to type "LAPTOP-OOHVP7Q7\MSSQLSERVER2016"

In your case your Hostname is "PC", try to add your instance name that you find in your SQL Server Services.